# Read a JSON file in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to read JSON file using React.js which is stored in local drive in Mac. I tried using fetch() api but I get data undefined.
Heres my code.

```
fetch('http://localhost:300/107k.json')
    .then(req => console.log(req))
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

I am getting data as undefined.
How will I be able to read JSON file in react.js?

Comment: Have you placed the json file in root path for your local server?

Answer (score 12):

Just use `import` instead

```js
import react from 'react'

//... rest of imports

import MyJson from '../path/to/json/107k.json';
```

Comment: But the problem is I cannot import outside src

Comment: @AkashSateesh does your server (localhost:300) serves 107k.json? Also, I think you might want to use port 3000 instead because port numbers below 999 are usually reserved.

Comment: Sorry its 3000 only. I am using webpack server of react

Comment: What happens when you access localhost:3000/107k.json in your web browser, do you see the data? is 107k.json too big to be placed in your react project?

Comment: Beware of importing if your data changes as importing will cache the content

Answer (score 5):

The json() method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.

```
fetch('http://localhost:300/107k.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: I am getting it as XML format. res.json() parsing gives error

Comment: This is the right way, make sure your json is valid via https://jsonlint.com/ or something similar.